# Obter o drawable usado como imagem do CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

Sempre que eu tenho guardar a imagem associada a uma checkbox através do método `imagem = minha_checkbox.getButtonDrawable();` dá me sempre um erro chamado `call requires API level 23 (current min is 17)`

Como é que eu posso resolver isto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método [getButtonDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#getButtonDrawable()) só foi introduzido na classe CheckBox(CompoundButton) na versão 23 da API.

Tem duas soluções:

- Altera a versão mínima da aplicação para 23(`android:minSdkVersion="23"`).
- Recorre à classe [CompoundButtonCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CompoundButtonCompat.html) e utiliza o seu método estático [getButtonDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CompoundButtonCompat.html#getButtonDrawable(android.widget.CompoundButton)):

  ```
  imagem = CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(minha_checkbox);
  ```

  <sub>Nota: Necessita da Android Support Library, revision 23.0.1 ou superior.</sub>